# Matplotlib does not plot when using Apache Livy interpreter on Zeppelin

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin, livy

I am unable to use matplotlib with Apache Livy 0.5  on Zeppelin 0.8. Paragraph does not display the plot. Please check the sample code below:

```
%livy.pyspark
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
```

I am getting the following output

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x112774990>]
```

I also tried adding `plt.show()` but then the paragraph is never reaching finish state.

Comment: Maybe you can try ipython interpreter in zeppelin 0.8, here's one tutorial https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL3pqZmZkdS9lN2Q3ODNiODRkNjA0ZjVjODM1OWZlMWExZjM4OTk3Zi9ub3RlLmpzb24

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this works the same in Zeppelin, but in Jupyter with Sparkmagic/Livy you need to

**1. Register the DataFrame first**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('tblName')
```

**2. Run a `%%sql` cell magic to query the data, and output it to the local space**

```
%%sql -o Name_of_local_DataFrame -n 500

SELECT * FROM tblName
```

This is taken from the GitHub sparkmagic page ([sparkmagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic))

**3. Plot it locally**

```
%%local

%matplotlib inline

... (your matplotlib code here; access the data via Name_of_local_DataFrame)
```

If this does not work, maybe share some more information on your setup and how you connect to your cluster.